# Strange exceptions on Visual Studio 2015 native C++ unit testing startup

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

When I run simple unit test for native C++ I receive many exceptions before testing framework hits my breakpoint on first line of unit test. The exceptions have been shown below.
**How to switch them off or what to do to fix them?**

I see also every single step in debugger takes signifficant time like in case of debugging on remote machine. **Is it normal in case of native unit testing?**

```
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0628D4D4.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0628D4D4.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0628C1B4.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

*** HR originated : -2147024774
* **   Source File : d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\copyout.cpp, line 1391


* ** HR propagated : -2147024774
* **   Source File : d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\identityauthority.cpp, line 278

Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0628C28C.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
... A lot of similar lines ...
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0628BFCC.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0628BFCC.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0628BFCC.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x76BAA6F2 in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Microsoft C++ exception : [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.

*** HR originated : -2147024774
* **   Source File : d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\copyout.cpp, line 1391


* ** HR propagated : -2147024774
* **   Source File : d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\identityauthority.cpp, line 278


* ** HR originated : -2147024774
* **   Source File : d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\copyout.cpp, line 1391


* ** HR propagated : -2147024774
* **   Source File : d:\iso_whid\x86fre\base\isolation\com\identityauthority.cpp, line 278
```

***Update 1:***

It has been called from clr for sure as on call stack info shown below (so for sure before reaching first line in my unit test).

[image]

Comment: EEFileLoadException is an exception that's raised by the .NET CLR.  Without a stack trace it is impossible to guess whether they came from the unit test runner or your code.  "A lot of similar lines" doesn't exactly give it high odds that it is the unit test runner that's misbehaving.  Force the debugger to stop on the exception so you can see more: Debug > Windows > Exception Settings > tick the "C++ exceptions" box.  If that points at your code then set the Debugger Type to "mixed" so you can see the managed exception.

Comment: I updated call stack info, but as I mentioned previously, it happens before reaching first line in my unit test ... :)

Comment: You did not enable the symbol server so we still don't know anything.  Not so sure you'll get there with the debugger.  Ask for help from another team member, ask him to run same unit tests.  If it doesn't repo on his machine then you know it is wonky machine problem.

Comment: I enabled symbol server - it's what VS was able to show

Comment: Try selecting all (click in list then `CTRL+A`), right-click then press `Load Symbols`.